# angular smart-table sort for null values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, smart-table

Recently I was use angular smart-table. The `st-sort` works fine except one thing: when the sort field contains empty value, it place the empty value in the middle of the sort between `n` and `m`. How can I make the empty value always at the bottom when sorting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bug (IMO) with smart-table and treating null, undefined, and empty strings inconsistently when sorting. null values are converted to their string representation of 'null' and then sorted, hence why they always get placed between n and m.

I've logged an issue: https://github.com/lorenzofox3/Smart-Table/issues/669

```
And repro plunkr:
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/BEBdzWI44z3BiIxRRDET?p=preview